# How do I create different number of columns for different widgets in Shiny APP?

Tags: r, shiny, widget

I want to created 2 columns for the first widget, and 6 columns for the other widget, but my code set both the widgets 6 columns.

ui <- fluidPage(
tags$head(
tags$style(HTML('
.shiny-split-layout>div {overflow: hidden;}
.multicol {

```
   -webkit-column-count: 6; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

   -moz-column-count: 6; /* Firefox */

   column-count: 6;

 }
                    ')),
```

)

.....

```
          tags$div(
            class = 'multicol',
          
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "imputation_cell",
                           label = NULL,
                           choices = cell,
                           selected = "FF1")
        )
```

......

I have add the above code to created 6 columns for one of the widgets, but for another widget, I just want to 2 columns, how do I do it as the 6 columns was set right under the fluidPage.
Are there any other methods to set different number of columns for different widgets?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.